# How can an AppCheck token be requested?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-app-check

I am testing the sending/receiving of Firebase HTTP v1 API Cloud Messages using an iOS emulator.

I am finding a problem where push notifications are not being received on the device after being sent via my Flutter application's API or via the Firebase console using the test facility.

I believe the situation is Firebase AppCheck at work because the error messages noticed state that the FCM token is invalid, which is ridiculous, but it would make sense from the perspective of AppCheck being unable to confirm that the API calls being handled originate from verified sources.

When completing these tests on an Android device, AppCheck sends a token around the time of building the project, and that token can then be pasted into my project's AppCheck zone to fully activate AppCheck for Android purposes.

With this iOS device/emulator, I have found that AppCheck is not delivering a token, and that seems to be the problem I am experiencing if I should guess why the push notifications are not arriving and why the FCM token is being rejected.

So my question is, can an AppCheck token be requested, and how if "yes"?

Ideally, the token would be requested from within Flutter to be printed within Flutter's debugging tools.  My Flutter application's server works with Node.js.

Please share your thoughts.

With thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed a Firebase document offering directions on acquiring an AppCheck token for debugging with an iOS device: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider

This probably answers my question.  And hopefully it also aids a resolution of the underlying problem as well.

Comment: The underlying problem was an absence of push notifications despite all of the coding, and the absence of an AppCheck token was my suspicion, however, having finally achieved the push notifications for iOS devices, what I found was that an AppCheck token was not required at all.  In the process towards iOS notifications, there were important Stack/Github answers I relied on, but the star in finally getting there has to be Apple's Xcode app, for being so friendly and useful with information - information that Android Studio does not give.